# return javascript code full of 's, "s and \s from within a class, how can I do it?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a very long javascript (so long that it's too long to escape manually every single problematic character) that I need to return from a method inside a class. Are there way to return (return not echo or print) safely this kind of code?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're after [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax or [output buffering](http://php.net/ob_start):

```
$str = <<<EOD

function javascript() { alert("foo"); }

EOD;

// or

ob_start();
?>
function javascript() { alert("foo"); }
<?php
$str = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: +1 For HEREDOC. Output buffering seems like an overkill to me in this case (although I can imagine a some scenarions where it would be The Right Thing).

Comment: Never considered ob_get_clean(), thank you I learned something new. Will use EOD though..

Comment: `EOD` is not part of the syntax. You can use any identifier (if `EOD` appears in your JavaScript, for example.) The identifier consists of alphanumeric characters and/or underscores, but may not begin with a number.

Comment: Wait I have a problem if i do this: $return .= <<<EOD EOD; I get a syntax error, unexpected $end

Comment: the "EOD;" has to be on a new line and can't be indented at all